# Clojure: core.logic, prolog, logic style programming in Clojure

Tags: clojure

### Context

I'm aware of core.logic.

I have worked through the reasoned schemer.

I know about the existence of Prolog.

I want to become better at doing logic-style programming *in* Clojure.

There are infinitely more Prolog books than core.logic books.

### Question:

I'm currently planning to work through a few Prolog books with clojure's core.logic. What things should I watch out for / what things are hard to map from Prolog to core.logic?

(Other suggestions at becoming better at logic programming welcome too.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a considerable amount of Prolog could be translated to miniKanren / core.logic. I'm not aware of many issues (one is Definite Clause Grammars, but there other ways to write parsers in Clojure). If you encounter difficulties feel free to post suggestions for improvement to the Clojure mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

Other parts of the logic-programming + Clojure world include

- cascalog (logic programming on Hadoop)
- datomic (logic programming + time on a database)